# Generating a deck of cards in C

Tags: c

I need some help with my assignment. We are supposed to generate and print all 52 cards, but I'm having trouble understanding how to print "Ace", "2".....etc.

Comment: Another array with the rank names?

Comment: You already figured it out for the suits. It's no different for the card ranks.

Comment: So am I getting a little bit closer? It will now display the face but repeats "King" for all Hearts, "Ace" for all Diamonds, and the repeats for the rest of the suits

Comment: two loops would make it more readable IMHO for (suit = 0; suit < 4; ++suit) for (value = 0; value < 13; ++value) then just use the variables directly as index in the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i < 52; i++)
{ 
    if(i%13==0)
    {
      printf("Card %2d = King %s\n", i,suits[i/13]); 
    }
    else if(i%13==1)
    {
      printf("Card %2d = Ace %s\n", i,suits[i/13]); 
    }
    else if(i%13==11)
    {
      printf("Card %2d = Jack %s\n", i,suits[i/13]); 
    }
    else if(i%13==12)
    {
      printf("Card %2d = Queen %s\n", i,suits[i/13]); 
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Card %2d = %2d %s\n", i, i%13, suits[i/13]); 
    }
}
```

Another solution is adding more condition into loop for "King" "Ace" "Jack" and "Queen"

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop put a switch statement:

```
int temp = i%13;
switch(temp) 
{
 case (0):
    printf("Card %2d = King %s\n", i, suits[i/13]); 
   break;
 case (1):
    printf("Card %2d = Ace %s\n", i, suits[i/13]); 
   break;

 . . .

default:
    printf("Card %2d = %2d %s\n", i, i%13, suits[i/13]); 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general theme of the answer would be writing a translation scheme for numbers to values. So you would have to have an intermediary translating card numbers to their names, should they have one

```
char * card_name(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0: return "King";
        case 1: return "Ace";
        case 11: return "Jack";
        case 12: return "Queen";
        default: return inttostr(number);
    }
}
```

then you would have to rewrite your printing statement:

```
printf("Card %2d = %2d of %s\n", i, card_name(i%13), suits[i/13]);
```

which will give you:

```
Card 0 = King of Hearts
Card 1 = Ace of Hearts
```

Comment: It's less hassle to include `case 2: return "2";` etc. than worry about memory allocation for `inttostr`.

Comment: Would this use a _global_ variable or require caller to free the result of some strings? An array of `const char * const foo[13]={"King","Ace", ..., "2", "3", "4", ..., "9" }; will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can put to use the modulo (%) operator.

```
char *suits[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"}; 
char *face[13] = {"King", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen"};

int main( ) 
{ 
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < 52; i++) { 
        printf("Card %2d = %s %s\n", i, face[i % 13], suits[i / 13]); 
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Online compiler link: http://ideone.com/xsRTEy